# How to write custom annotation that processes a field

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, annotations

i am delving into annotations and would like someone to point me in the right direction.

I want to create an annotation that will be able to trim the String value when it is being mapped from a JSON into a POJO.

Not sure how to do that.

i.e.

```
@trim
private String referenceField;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringStripDeserializer.class)
public @interface @Strip {}

class StringStripDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

   @Override 
   public Date deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException { 
      String text = parser.getText();
      return text != null ? text.strip : null;
   }
   ...
}
```

Or, if you want to trim *all* the strings:

```
    @Bean
    public Module stringStripModule() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(String.class, (JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) => {
            String string = super.deserialize(jsonParser, deserializationContext);
            return Objects.nonNull(string) ? string.strip() : null;
        });
        return module;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, will try it out now. Want to know what is the difference between @JacksonAnnotation and @JacksonAnnotationsInside?

Comment: I'm not sure what `@JacksonAnnotation` is, but `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` signals to Jackson that the `@Trim` annotation is itself annotated with Jackson annotations which should be honoured wherever `@Trim` is applied