# Is there any Auto trim way available after getting results back from Database in spring

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, trim

I am using Spring-Boot with MyBatis, with MSSQL server database.
There is no hold for me as such since data exist in column with lot of pre and post spaces. I can nothing do with data.

What I wants is once my Mapper holds data in the respective data type I want to either add any annotation to trim all the properties of My Object or I have to write 1 transformation layer which willread one by one properties and then remove spaces from each. the later approach I think more complicated and more coding involved.

Is there any simpler way or any simple annotation with which this is possible.

My Service Class is

```
@Component
public class GetEmpData{
    @Autowired
    private EMPRepository empRepo;

    List<Emp> emps= empRepo.findAll();
}
```

My Emp class as

```
@Data //Lombok annotations
public class Emp{
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

My Repo class as it is

```
public EMPRepository extends CrudRepository<EMP, Long>{

}
```

My Database holding data as follows

```
SELECT * FROM EMP;
------------------------
id | Name   | DOB
------------------------
1  | Test   | 01-01-1990
2  |  Test  | 01-01-1990
3  |   Test | 01-01-1990
------------------------
3 record(s) found
```

My Out put in Json as following

```
{
  [
    {"id":1,"name":"test "},{"id":2,"name":" test "},{"id":3,"name":" test "}
  ]
}
```

Note: In above records there are pre and post spaces at individual records.

I tried to fix  using creating Java annotation, but there I am not getting how this will work.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does these spaces makes sense somewhere else? If not then simply clear/normalize your data by one query (and modify your code preventing such values).

Comment: Since there is DB migration process and it should take care. but unfortunately for me as a response provider I need to handle those spaces.

Comment: You could try [overriding the default `String`/`VARCHAR` type mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-registry) with a `Type` that uses `String.strip()` before returning the entity representation. Additionally, if you want to trim input `String`s as well, consider [registering a custom `String` deserializer with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872036/1092818)

Comment: It's also possible to write a custom [type handler](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers).